# Editing the edit summary

Tags: feature-request, editing

It happens to me quite often that I do an edit, only to realize, when I click the `Save Edits` button, that I should comment on the edit in the `Edit Summary`. However, this seems impossible (if I go again into the edit mode, and I'm still in the grace period, the changes into the edit summary are ignored.

Could this please be changed? The way how it works now seems to be confusing, and the feature is really missing.